# How can adjust the axis so that I don't have unused space in dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have the following dash script

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

# Generate random data for demonstration
random.seed(42)  # For reproducibility
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'fr': list(range(1, 25001)),
    'X1': [random.uniform(1, 10) for _ in range(25000)],
    'Y1': [random.uniform(5, 20) for _ in range(25000)],
    'X2': [random.uniform(1, 10) for _ in range(25000)],
    'Y2': [random.uniform(5, 20) for _ in range(25000)]
})

# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Data Filtering with Dash"),
    
    # RangeSlider for selecting the range of 'fr' values
    html.Div([
        html.Label("Select a Range of 'fr' Values:"),
        dcc.RangeSlider(
            id="fr-range",
            min=1,
            max=25000,
            step=1,
            marks={i: str(i) for i in range(1, 25001, 5000)},
            value=[1, 25000],
        ),
        html.Div(id='range-display')
    ]),
    
    # Plot displayed
    dcc.Graph(id='scatter-plot', config={'displayModeBar': False}, style={'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'}),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('scatter-plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('fr-range', 'value')]
)
def update_plot(range_value):
    min_value, max_value = range_value

    filtered_data = data[(data['fr'] >= min_value) & (data['fr'] <= max_value)]

    hover_text_1 = [
        f'fr: {fr}<br>X1: {x:.2f}<br>Y1: {y:.2f}'
        for fr, x, y in zip(filtered_data['fr'], filtered_data['X1'], filtered_data['Y1'])
    ]
    hover_text_2 = [
        f'fr: {fr}<br>X2: {x:.2f}<br>Y2: {y:.2f}'
        for fr, x, y in zip(filtered_data['fr'], filtered_data['X2'], filtered_data['Y2'])
    ]

    fig = go.Figure()

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=filtered_data['X1'],
        y=filtered_data['Y1'],
        mode='markers',
        text=hover_text_1,
        name='(X1, Y1) Data'
    ))

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=filtered_data['X2'],
        y=filtered_data['Y2'],
        mode='markers',
        text=hover_text_2,
        name='(X2, Y2) Data'
    ))

    fig.update_layout(title_text='Data')
    fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 15])  # Set X-axis range to match the data range

    # fig.update_layout(aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1))  # Set aspect ratio for square plot
    fig.update_xaxes(scaleanchor='y', scaleratio=1)  # Set the X axis to have the same scale as the Y axis

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The script works fine but it gives me this

[image]

which as you can see gives me a lot of unused space for X. My data only goes from around 0 to 15 but the X axis goes from -50 to 60

How can I eliminate this unused space.

Take into account that the ration of the axis X and Y has to be the same

I have tried to use

```
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 15])
```

but that did not change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of plotly v5.17.0 you can set min and max allowed range as follows:

```py
fig.update_xaxes(minallowed=0,maxallowed=15)
```